# como fazer um if com parametros php dentro do javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso fazer uma verificação antes de alterar elementos html, tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou não entra no if em nenhuma circunstancia.

```
    <script>
    if("<?php empty($usuario_pesquisado->getArea()->getNome()) ?>")
    {
        $('#area_item').css("opacity", 0.4);
    }
    if("<?php  empty($usuario_pesquisado->getFormacao()) ?>")
    {
        $('#formacao_item').css("opacity", 0.4);
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Utilize a condição no PHP, caso o resultado seja verdadeiro, você imprime o código JS com o `echo`. Caso seu PHP seja a versão 7+, utilize `<?php echo (!empty($usuario_pesquisado->getArea()->getNome())) ?: '$('#area_item').css("opacity", 0.4);' ?>`

Comment: Sim uso php 7, infelizmente não funcionou :/

Comment: utiliza o `if`. Base: http://codepad.org/Bc75rDMf

Comment: vlw amigo, agora funcionou :D

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu faria uma request com AJAX pegando os valores da pagina PHP:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```